# Use Pagy gem with group_by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagy

I've created a Resource where I want to group each response by an attribute from an belong_to association.

I've accomplished that with the following code:

**fixtures_controller.rb**

```
 def index
    @q = Fixture.ransack(params[:q])
    scope = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @fixture_leagues = scope.filter_by_date_range.group_by {|fixture| fixture.league.name}
  end
```

**fixtures/index.erb**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "table" do %>
<p class="loading">Loading...</p>
<div class="-mx-4 overflow-hidden sm:-mx-6 md:mx-0">
    <ul compact="container mx-auto gap-4 list-none">
    <%# render @fixtures %>
    <% @fixture_leagues.each do |league, fixtures| %>
      <h2 class="text-base"><%= league %></h2>  
      <% fixtures.each do |fixture| %>
        <%= render partial:  "fixture", locals: {fixture: fixture} %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My issue is that the response can sometimes be really large so I want to have som pagination on the response. But do not know how to accomplish that with a grouped response?

I use Pagy Gem for pagination for my other resources.

And I want the response to be

**League 1**
Fixture 1
Fixture 2
Fixture 3

**League 2**
Fixture 4
Fixture 5

**League 3**
Fixture 6
Fixture 7
Fixture 8
Fixture 9
Fixture 10

(trigger pagination) to see more items.

Comment: Do you have any code/attempted code for pagy?

Comment: you can use `arel`, Please have a look at here https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/extras/arel.html#gsc.tab=0